# Build error- Error executing Static Binding Generator: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior

Tags: webpack, migration, fragment, nativescript, node-modules

I'm Migrating my nativescript application to the current version.
I'm getting this error "Error executing Static Binding Generator: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.Please change the name of one of the extended classes."

my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@mashdog/nativescript-accordion": "^7.0.6",
    "@nativescript/android": "^8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.0.2",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^13.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^2.0.4",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.1.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "8.0.1",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.6.3",
    "nativescript-ratings": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-ripple": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^10.0.2",
    "nativescript-youtubeplayer": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.27",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^6.5.15",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  }
}
```

[image: click here to see error image]

when I run this command "ns build android --log trace" getting error as

[image: Click here to see error image]

when I run this command "ns run android --log trace" getting error as

[image: Click here to see error image]

Also referred some solution but not getting possible solution.
Please help me with the solution, where I'm getting the error and how to solve the error.

Comment: One of your dependencies are invalid, you can try to run "ns clean" and then build your project again once you removed the dependency from the "package.json"

This happened to me when I tried to add a non angular dependency to my angular nativescript project.